# A chain of six circles associated with a conic

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, curves, conic-sections

I found this problems three years ago. But I never have been a proof. Recently I [posted in math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707012/a-chain-of-six-circles-associated-with-a-conic).  I am looking for a solution of the following problems:

**A chain of six circles associated with a conic.**

> Let $A_1, ..., A_6$ and $B_1, ..., B_6$ be 12 points lying on a conic, and suppose that for $i=1, ..., 5$ through $A_i, A_{i+1}, B_{i+1}, B_i$ passes a circle $(O_i)$. Then through $A_6, B_6, A_1, B_1$ as well passes a circle $(O_6)$. Let $P_1, P_4$ be intersection points of $(O_1)$ and $(O_4)$; the same for $P_2, P_5$ and $P_3, P_6$. Show that:
>
> 1. Three lines $O_1O_4$, $O_2O_5$, and $O_3O_6$ have a common point $O$.
> 2. Six points $P_1, ..., P_6$ lie on a circle with center in $O$.

[image: Drawing to the problem]

**My remark:** With six points and six lines we get the [Pascal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem). With 12 points and six circles we have this problem

- I checked it by Geogebra, But I can not calculate.
- See also: [Sequences of Concyclic Points on a Conic](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/ConcyclicPointsOnConic.shtml) and [Geogebra A chain of six circles associated with a conic](http://www.geogebra.org/material/simple/id/1544841)
- [There are two other chains of six circles](http://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvYS9iLzcyODQ2MTU1OGU3NWQyY2JlNGU0MTdmNTMyMjU2NWU5MmU4MTgyLnBkZg==&rn=VGhyZWUgY2hhaW5zIG9mIFNpeCBjaXJjbGVzLnBkZg==)

Comment: [You can see the problem in](https://tube.geogebra.org/material/simple/id/1544841)

Comment: Your second question follows from the fact that if $ABCD$, $A_1ABB_1$, $B_1BCC_1$, and $C_1CDD_1$ are cyclic quadrilaterals then $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ is a cyclic quadrilateral if and only if $A_1ADD_1$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. This fact can be proved by a straightforward angle chase.

Comment: Have you tried solving it by brute force calculation? You can parameterize the conic, pick $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5,A_6,B_1$ for generic values of parameters, and proceed to calculate $B_2,...,B_6$, as well as $O_1,...,O_6$. It might be beyond the usual software's capabilities, but it might not be.

Comment: @LevBorisov I checked it by Geogebra many times, But I can not calculate. Please see: [Sequences of Concyclic Points on a Conic](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/ConcyclicPointsOnConic.shtml) and [Geogebra A chain of six circles associated with a conic](http://www.geogebra.org/material/simple/id/1544841)

Comment: And if points do not belong to a conic, this fails?

Comment: Dear Dr. @FedorPetrov , [please see problem 1 in here](http://www.journal-1.eu/2016-2/Dao-Thanh-Oai-sixteen-points-pp.21-24.pdf)

Comment: Dear Dr. @FedorPetrov , the result is right iff : Case 1: 12 points $A_1,A_2,.....A_6, B_1, B_2,...,B_6$ lie on a conic. Case 2: 6 points $A_1,A_2,.....A_6$   lie on a circles, and six points $B_1, B_2,...,B_6$ lie on another circle. Case 3:  Six points $A_1,A_2,.....A_6$  lie on a line, and six points $B_1, B_2,...,B_6$ lie on another line.

Comment: Well, interesting. Remark: case 3 is a particular case of case 1.

Comment: Dear @FedorPetrov , Thanks to You. Remark: case 3 is also a particular case of case 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $С_1$, $C_2$, and your conic $\alpha$ pass through $A_2$ and $B_2$ we get that $A_1B_1$ and $A_3B_3$ are parallel (it calls three conic theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThreeConicsTheorem.html). Applying it several times to your construction you get that $C_6$ exists.

Intersection of $O_1O_4$, $O_2O_5$ and $O_3O_6$ follows from the Pappus theorem applied to the triple parallel lines $O_1O_2$, $O_3O_4$, and $O_5O_6$ and the triple $O_2O_3$, $O_4O_5$, and $O_6O_1$.

Upd. Regarding the second question:
@zeb was almost right. We need lemma with little bit different combinatorics:
$(abcd)$, $(aba_1b_1)$, $(abc_1d_1)$, $(cda_1b_1)$, $(cdc_1d_1)$ => $(a_1b_1c_1d_1)$.

Lets show that $P_1$, $P_4$, $P_3$, and $P_6$ lie on a circle. For that we note that the following quadruples circumscribed
$(A_2B_2A_5B_5)$, $(A_2B_2P_1P_4)$, $(A_2B_2P_3P_6)$, $(A_5B_5P_1P_4)$, $(A_5B_5P_3P_6)$ and then apply the Lemma.

It is clear that center of this circle is $O$ because it is lie on the corresponded perpendicular bisectors of $P_iP_{i+3}$.
Therefore all $P_i$ lie on the fixed circle with center at $O$.

Comment: Is your proof complete ?  @akopyan

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, what do you mean.

Comment: I mean: Do you proof $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5, P_6$ lie on a circle?

Comment: I thought it was answered by @zeb. But now I do not think his observation solves the problem. So, I do not know how to prove it

Comment: Following your suggestion: one question one topic. So, I removed the second question. So I think @zeb did not answer the question above.

Comment: I've updated the comment.

Comment: The proof is complete? @akopyan

Comment: I do not understand you again. Do you see any problem with it?

Comment: did you proof $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5, P_6$ lie on a circle? @akopyan

Comment: Yes, see the update.

Comment: please give your proof this problem: 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232571/sixteen-points-circle-a-conjecture-on-m%C3%B6bius-plane

Comment: You wrote: "the triple parallel lines $O_1O_2$, $O_3O_4$, and $O_5O_6$ and the triple $O_2O_3$, $O_4O_5$, and $O_6O_1$. It is mean: $O_1O_2$ parallel to $O_3O_4$ and parallel to $O_5O_6$ ? @ArseniyAkopyan

Comment: Yes. They are parallel because of the 3 conics theorem

Comment: @ArseniyAkopyan Thank You very much, Now I remmember You