# Can generalization of a generalization Pascal theorem, Pappus theorem to Higher Dimensions?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry, euclidean-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, conic-sections

Please see [a chain of six circles associated with a conic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234722/a-chain-of-six-circles-associated-with-a-conic). This is a generalization of Pascal theorem, Pappus theorem. I reformulate as following:

*Let $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ be six arbitrary points in a hyperbola. Let $1'$ be arbitrary point in the hyperbola. The circle $(121')$ meets the hyperbola at point $2'$. The circle $(232)$ meets the hyperbola again at $3'$, define points $4', 5', 6'$ similarly. Let circle $(121')$ meets the circle $(454')$ at $A, B$, Let circle $(232')$ meets the circle $(565')$ at $C, D$. Let circle $(343')$ meets the circle $(616') $ at $E, F$. Then six points $A, B, C, D, E, F$ lie on a circle.*

[image]

**Special case:**

*1. If $1'$ at $\infty$, six circles are six lines, so the theorem is [Pascal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem).*

*2. If the hyperbola is two lines, and $1'$ at $\infty$ then six circles are six lines, the theorem is [Pappus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem)*

[image]

> **My question:** Can generalization the result above to Higher Dimensions?

Comment: I don't know why some ones put on hold ?

Comment: MathOverflow is simply not the right place to ask questions about elementary Euclidean geometry, unless they are connected with research topics. Please post them on Math.Stackexchange instead.

Comment: This is a generalization of one great theorem in Euclidean Geometry. I ask can generalization this?

Comment: I understand, but this is not a research problem, and elementary Euclidean geometry is not a research topic, so this is not the right place.

Comment: Blaise Pascal died 355 years ago. Now the generalization have been found. So I think this generalization should be interest

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Euclidean and axiomatic geometry are research topics.

Comment: In first approximation, you could read about the Cayley Bacharach theorem, either in Griffiths-Harris's book, or in Eisenbud-Green-Harris's paper under the same title. Buckle up your safety belt first and embark for a wonderful ride into the world of modern algebraic geometry!